# SpringBootTest not loading applicationcontext when overriding its value dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I ma using @SpringBootTest for my IT and what I want to do is load a new ApplicationContext for every IT. For this I am overriding the SpringBootTest annotation dynamically and I am providing the same value for classes. But its throwing an exception saying could not load ApplicationContext. Is there an issue if we override the impl for SpringBootTest?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
public abstract class OrchestratorBootIT extends BaseIT {
private static final String ANNOTATIONS = "annotations";
public static final String ANNOTATION_DATA = "annotationData";

public static Class<? extends OrchestratorBootIT> runningTestClassType;

public OrchestratorBootIT() {
    if(runningTestClassType != null) return;

    StepsConfigDAOCacheIT.class.toString());
       try {

        SpringBootTest annotation = StepsConfigDAOCacheIT.class.getAnnotation(SpringBootTest.class);

        //In JDK8 Class has a private method called annotationData().
        //We first need to invoke it to obtain a reference to AnnotationData class which is a private class
        Method method = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod(ANNOTATION_DATA, null);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        //Since AnnotationData is a private class we cannot create a direct reference to it. We will have to
        //manage with just Object
        Object annotationData = method.invoke(StepsConfigDAOCacheIT.class);
        //We now look for the map called "annotations" within AnnotationData object.
        Field annotations = annotationData.getClass().getDeclaredField(ANNOTATIONS);
        annotations.setAccessible(true);
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> map =
                (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) annotations.get(annotationData);
        map.put(SpringBootTest.class, new SpringBootTestImpl());

        SpringBootTest annotation1 = StepsConfigDAOCacheIT.class.getAnnotation(SpringBootTest.class);

        log.info("test");
    } catch (Exception  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    BaseIT.beforeClass();
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterClass() {
    runningTestClassType = null;
}

@After
public void cleanup() {
    super.cleanup();
}

private boolean setDynamicSpringBootTestAnnotation(final Object annotationData) throws Exception {
    Field annotations = annotationData.getClass().getDeclaredField("annotations");
    annotations.setAccessible(true);

    Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> map = (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) annotations.get(annotationData);
    map.put(SpringBootTest.class, getSpringBootTest());

    return true;
}

protected SpringBootTest getSpringBootTest() {
    return new SpringBootTestImpl();
}

static class SpringBootTestImpl implements SpringBootTest {

    @Override
    public String[] value() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] properties() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?>[] classes() {
        return new Class[] {CacheConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    public WebEnvironment webEnvironment() {
        return WebEnvironment.MOCK;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return SpringBootTestImpl.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it might be unapropriate, but let me as you a favor.... code please ??????

Comment: added plz check the post